# VBA Excel Copy Content From Word Table

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Word file that contains a table and I am going through the tables in the Word file and putting them into an Excel file

```
Example Word File:
-----------------------------------
|Col Header 1  | Col Header 2     |
-----------------------------------
|Content 1     | Content 2 line 1 |
|              | line 2           |
----------------------------------
```

When I try to paste that content or transfer it excel it either removes the new line and mashes the content together or if I use paste special it puts line 1 and line 2 into new rows.

This code puts the content together:

```
Cells(x, y) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(wdDoc.tables(1).cell(6, 1).Range.Text)

Result in excel:
----------------------------------------
|Col Header 1  | Col Header 2          |
---------------------------------------
|Content 1     | Content 2 line 1line2 |
----------------------------------------
```

This code puts the content on multiple rows

```
wdDoc.tables(1).cell(6, 1).Range.Copy    
Sheet1.Cells(x, y).Select
Sheet1.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False

Result in excel:
----------------------------------------
|Col Header 1  | Col Header 2          |
---------------------------------------
|Content 1     | Content 2 line 1      |
----------------------------------------
|              | line2                 |
----------------------------------------
```

I only care about the new lines, don't necessarily care about the formatting. I'll accept formatting if that's the only option but I can't seem to find a way to get it to even transfer the content properly. I've tried copying it as a formula, different pastespecial types with no luck.

Greatly appreciate the help

Comment: Are you sure it actually have a `newline` instead of msword just wrapping the content?

Comment: Definitely a new line. The content has spacing between it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing all the carriage returns with line breaks.  Excel can handle line breaks but as you've seen will put carriage returns on a separate cell.

```
Sub TextToExcel()
    Dim wdDoc As Document, wdTab As Table
    Dim ii As Integer, jj As Integer, kk As Integer
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application

    Set wdTab = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)

    ReDim Data(1 To wdTab.Rows.Count, 1 To wdTab.Columns.Count)

    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    With xlApp.ActiveSheet
        For ii = 1 To wdTab.Rows.Count
            For jj = 1 To wdTab.Columns.Count
                Data(ii, jj) = VBA.Replace(wdTab.Cell(ii, jj).Range.Text, vbCr, vbLf)
            Next jj
        Next ii

        'Place the data
        With .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(wdTab.Rows.Count, wdTab.Rows.Count))
            .Value = Data
            .WrapText = True
        End With
    End With

    Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

*Note, I haven't tested this with line breaks in the word document.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! I knew it should have been something as simple as replacing the new line breaks

Comment: Some old word doco's contain funky chars: `Data(ii, jj) = Replace(Replace(wdTab.Cell(ii, jj).Range.Text, vbCr, vbLf), Chr(10), "")`